# Integer Range to vector

Tags: vhdl

I've had an issue converting a vectors inputs to integers in my code. I am new to VHDL but the below code works with the integer RANGE commented out code but there is an error when I try to convert the vector values to an integers. Here is a copy of my code and error:

[image: screenshot]

Update1:
I've tried your fix and it takes care of one of the errors but the new error message and code looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is still an error that looks like this :                                                                      Error (10409): VHDL Type Conversion error at dataRAM_inferred.vhd(26): converted type of object near text or symbol "UNSIGNED" must match integer type of target object

Comment: Please paste your code and your error message into your question. Links have a habit of breaking.

Comment: @CedrickBaker You should really copy and paste your code and error messages rather than posting screenshots of them. Images are bad because a) anyone who wants to debug your code has to type it out from your screenshot, which is a horrible thing to do (and error-prone) and b) images make it impossible for search engines to index your post in a meaningful way.

Comment: The range `integer range 0 to ASIZE - 1` is not the same as `std_logic_vector(ASIZE - 1 downto 0)`. It needs to be `integer range 0 to 2**ASIZE - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

In according to your declaration in follow line `type mem is array (...) of std_logic_vector(...)` your memory waits for `std_logic_vector` type rather than `unsigned` like in your assignment `RAMArray(unsigned(addr)) <= unsigned(din)`.

Here it is not sufficient to only use a type conversion to `unsigned`, but you have to add type conversion function `to_integer` in the argument. In other words

```
RAMArray(to_integer(unsigned(addr))) <= din
```

The second error is in the follow line `qout <= RAMArray(addr)`. Here you should also use both the type conversion to `unsigned` as well as the type conversion function `to_integer`. The location parameter would be of the integer type. Example:

```
qout <= RAMArray(to_integer(unsigned(addr)))
```

Try to fix your code with my suggestions and I think it will work.

Comment: tried this fix and it takes away the error with the un-necessary casting to din. but now it gives me the error.                                                 
 Error (10409): VHDL Type Conversion error at dataRAM_inferred.vhd(26): converted type of object near text or symbol "UNSIGNED" must match integer type of target object

Comment: Maybe this is because you use `positive` type for `ASIZE` and `DSIZE`. Try to use casting to integer, as following `RAMArray(to_integer(unsigned(addr))) <= din` and `qout <= RAMArray(to_integer(unsigned(addr)))`. Or just use `natural` type for generic values.

Comment: The to_integer fix seemed to have worked...... i am new at this and will be spending the next couple of hours figuring out and reading over your answer... Thank you for your assistance Roman.

Comment: If you will have some questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the `to_integer` _type conversion function_ call, rather than expecting future readers to follow a conversation in the comments. You might want to emphasise the difference between a _type conversion_ and a _type conversion function_, too, rather than calling it "casting", which is not a term used in VHDL.

Comment: @Roman I waved through your edit to the question because I earlier came across the rejected edit to your answer and recognised the content. In the future when adding content to a post, be sure to make it _abundantly_ clear where that content is coming from - your edit had 2 reject votes already (and quite rightfully so).

Comment: @Siguza I just move an author's answer from my answer's edit suggestion to the question, because the author added it by mistake (I think) to wrong place

Comment: @Roman Yes, but until you reach 2000 reputation, edits you make to other users' posts will be placed in a review queue where other users have to decide whether your edit is appropriate or not. Without the context of the other reject edit (which one could only know about by pure chance), your edit would seem highly unsanctioned.